# what's the reasons about this:'ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: & reshape your data using array.reshape(-1, 1)'?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

while executing the code:

```
StandardScaler().fit( data['Age'] )
```

the error was

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:  &  Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

I've looked around and solved by executing:

```
StandardScaler().fit( data['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1) )
```

However, in my limited experience, i want to understand why should use two-dimensional  array data as a parameter. can you give an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You have a **single feature/variable** so you have to reshape it into a column vector and use `sc.fit(a.reshape(-1,1))`:

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

 a = np.array([10, 20, 30])
 sc = StandardScaler()
 sc.fit(a.reshape(-1,1))
```

**Use**:

```
StandardScaler().fit( data['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass age as a Pandas Dataframe and not Pandas series? You are passing a series if you use one bracket.

```py
d = StandardScaler().fit( data[['Age']])
```

Note the double brackets `[[ ]]`.

Comment: thanks, as you suggested it works. But why two dimensions instead of one ?

Comment: It is because `print(df[['age']].shape, df['age'].shape)` gives `(Rows, Column)`, `(Rows,)`.

Comment: i may find a clue about memeroy addressing modes of arrays . thanks！